# Example of creating a shell script link in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

[The org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html) states that org-mode will """...execute the command in a shell link""" but it does not show the syntax for such a link.

I would appreciate a simple complete working example of how such a shell-link could work. Perhaps for doing `ls -l` on a directory... e.g.:

```
[[see all my files][shell://cd ~/files; ls -larth]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal text is `[[shell:ls%20~][foo]]`.
If you use <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> to insert links, `org-mode` will auto-escape spaces
and other things for you.

Comment: It's not working for me. It considers the whole thing as a link. It works well only with shell:ls, but as soon as I put %20, it breaks.